# trying to connect to a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have an HTML form, and I need to past data from it to mysql database in phpMyAdmin. I'm far from php and I don't know what to do with these errors, also I was unable to set up server and phpMyAdmin locally so I test it right away on the hosting.

index.html:

```
<section class="form">
        <form class="form__wrapper" action="form.php" method="post">
            <h2 class="form__wrapper_text">Leave your contacts below</h2>
            <div class="form__wrapper_inputs">
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_number">
                    <p>Phone</p>
                    <input type="tel" value="+380">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_name">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_company">
                   <p>Company</p>
                   <input type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_email">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_energy" >
                    <p>Consumption</p>
                    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="form__wrapper_inputs_send">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </section>
```

form.php:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "***Link to phpmyadmin of my hosting***";
$dbuser = "***phpmyadmin unsername***";
$dbpass = "***phpmyadmin password";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $consumption = $_POST['consumption'];

    $insert = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `form`(`number`, `name`, `company`, `email`, `consumption`) VALUES ('$number',
    '$name', '$company', '$email', '$consumption')");

    if(!$insert)
    {
        echo mysqli_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Records added successfully.";
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When I press submit button, I get following errors:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve in /sata2/home/users/***user***/www/***site***/form.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve in /sata2/home/users/***user***/www/***site***/form.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /sata2/home/users/***user***/www/***site***/form.php on line 8
Could not connect:
```

In comments I've been told that `$dbhost` variable is wrong, but I'm not sure what to use there. If I assign it IP of my hosting, I get timed out error.

Comment: dbhost should is server name. exp : localhost or abc.com. it is not Link to phpmyadmin of my hosting

Comment: @MaiTruong so the address of my site? Or what server?

Comment: Yes, Your server. You need Specifies a host name or an IP address

Comment: @MaiTruong but in what way will it access phpmyadmin?

Comment: mysqli_connect() function opens a new connection to the MySQL server.
https://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

Comment: @MaiTruong let's say my hosting is hosting.com, and phpmyadmin is accessible by db.hosting.com/phpmyadmin, and also my site is site.com. What should I write? I tried db.hosting.com (same error) and hosting.com (operation timed out)

Comment: please note that **Phpmyadmin** is a tool to connect to the database, not a DB itself. You are connecting to your **mysql** installation and you should have an ip address or localhost. The address to connect to phpmyadmin here is not relevant

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is just a regular web site, like Google or Amazon. There're no point in trying to connect to it from a MySQL client of any kind, PHP or not. You need to get your MySQL Server's credentials and use those instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be network configuration. The database server is blocking ext-connection to port 3306.

```
$dbhost = "***Link to phpmyadmin of my hosting***";
$dbuser = "***phpmyadmin unsername***";
$dbpass = "***phpmyadmin password";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Those info should be:

```
$dbhost = "***Database server IP***";
$dbuser = "***phpmyadmin unsername***";
$dbpass = "***phpmyadmin password";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Make sure your server open port **3306** from your webserver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

index.html (note: you are missing the HTML input element name attributes, so nothing is being sent)

```html
<section class="form">
        <form class="form__wrapper" action="form.php" method="post">
            <h2 class="form__wrapper_text">Leave your contacts below</h2>
            <div class="form__wrapper_inputs">
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_number">
                    <p>Phone</p>
                    <input name="number" type="tel" value="+380">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_name">
                    <p>Name</p>
                    <input name="name" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_company">
                   <p>Company</p>
                   <input name="company type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_email">
                    <p>Email</p>
                    <input name="email" type="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form__wrapper_inputs_energy" >
                    <p>Consumption</p>
                    <input name="consumption" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="form__wrapper_inputs_send">Submit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </section>
```

form.php

```php
<?php

// check if form is empty out here before wasting a database connection
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {

    $dbname = "database_name"; // you must specify the database name
    $dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
    $dbuser = "database_username"; // add your username here
    $dbpass = "database_password"; // add your password here

    // use PDO instead, it is safer than mysqli functions
    // see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

    // pdo options
    $pdo_options = [
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ];

    try {

        // connect to database
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8mb4", $dbuser, $dbpass, $pdo_options);

        // use prepared statements to help prevent sql injection

        // insert query
        $query = "INSERT INTO `form` (`number`, `name`, `company`, `email`, `consumption`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        // prepare statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        // execute with bound parameters
        $stmt->execute([
            $_POST['number'],
            $_POST['name'],
            $_POST['company'],
            $_POST['email'],
            $_POST['consumption']
        ]);

        // success
        echo "Form submitted successfully";

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // error
        echo "Error inserting record into database, " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting to mysql not to phpmyadmin.

So you should change your credentials like this:

```
$dbhost = "***Link to mysql of my hosting***";
$dbuser = "***mysql username***";
$dbpass = "***mysql password";
```

These credentials have been provided to you by your hosting. `$dbuser` and `$dbpass` are the same that you use for phpmyadmin but the dbhost should be different

Comment: Thanks! I found the mysql link. I don't get an error, but still the data doesn't appear in phpmyadmin. I understand that it's outside of the question and you still get bounty for answer, but I would be very thankful if you could show me a direction where to move.

Comment: simply put, in your form, each input should have a `name` attribute that is the posted value. So for example to do ` $name = $_POST['name'];` you need an input with `name="name"` in your html. If you fix this you should be able to post to your database

Comment: note that you should learn how to use prepared statements since your code is open to **SQL injections**

Comment: what is the error mysqli is throwing? Have you tried echoing the values before running the query? _"still not working"_ is not that usefull by itself